# Is it possible to share chunks between different rMarkdown templates

Tags: r-markdown

I have done a lot of analysis and I want to share the output with slides, posters, a written report etc. I could replicate the analysis in each of the reports but I'd like it to be co-ordinated (less error) so that if I make a change in one of the `Rmarkdown` files (say the parent `Rmarkdown`) then the chunk I have updated will also be updated in the slides, poster etc. etc.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read_chunk()` to do this.

Put the code into a file, with a marker at the top of each chunk of code

```
## ---- myChunk
rnd <- rnorm()
```

In the Rmd file, load the chunk with

```
knitr::read_chunk("myCode.R")
```

and run the chunk with

````
```{r myChunk}  
```
````

The chunk in the Rmd file should have no contents.

The same chunk can be used in multiple Rmd files.

An even better solution is to use the `drake` package. `drake` runs all the code and caches the results (keeping track of when code or data changes require analyses to be rerun). The objects in the cache can be read into the markdown file with `readd()` or `loadd()`.

Comment: Thanks @RichardTelford. I run a lot of the main body code from within an Rmd file rather than having it in a R file and loading it into a Rmd. Ideally then I would like to share some chunks from this main Rmd with another Rmd. Is this possible or do I always have to use an R intermediary file?